# Is really sugars present in fruits will increase belly fat?

Tags: bellyfat

As we all know sugar will increase belly fat, but what about sugar which present in fruits ?

so is we need to avoid fruits like **mango, banana** to reduce belly fat ?

If so what fruits i need to take and what i need to avoid ?

Comment: Sugar is still sugar. So yes, too much fruit sugar can be a problem. But it is more complex than avoiding banana, for example. Diet is a complex thing, changing one part (fruits) is not effective.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once again the most important thing is staying in a caloric deficit. There was an individual who only ate twinkies and donuts and still lost weight. Stop worrying too much about little things, just focus on eating healthy and not over eating.

Comment: np, good luck on your weight loss journey!

Comment: Thanks , with `twinkies and donuts` , great!....  `he showed us nothing is impossible`...... :)